# Blender Python query/list uv edges from selected uv face to do operations on

Tags: python, uv, edges, selection-tools

This is probably a pretty noob question but I'm trying to iterate through the uv edges of selected uv faces on an object to do operations like:
bpy.ops.uv.align(axis="ALIGN_AUTO")
I can't get any useful list that I can iterate through and for some reason I can't find anything on that.
Would be great if someone can help a complete newby when it comes to blender's python API.

Comment: Welcome, could you please explain a bit more what you tried it?

Comment: I do have a street layout with a lot of curved planes. When I unwrap the layout I get uvs where the faces are skewed to form the curve. 
My aim is to have a straight layout of the uvs for the curved streets to use a tileable street texture where the markings follow the curve. 
What I'm currently doing is select the edges of one uv face one by one and apply the ALIGN_AUTO command to make a perfect rectangle where each edge lays on an exact axis (u or v / xy). after that I select the face and apply the "Follow active quads" on it to make the uvs go in a straight line

Comment: You can use or refer to an addon called [UvSquares](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares).

Answer (score 0):

In the Blender docs there is [a code example](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html) that shows how faces and UV vertices are related.

This is a code snippet to print all the UV vertices of selected faces in the active mesh:

```
import bpy

# Force object mode, to ensure polygon selection is up to date
obj_mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode
if obj_mode != 'OBJECT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Get active object
obj = bpy.context.object.data

# Get active uv map
uv_layer = obj.uv_layers.active.data

# Iterate all faces in the mesh
for polygon in obj.polygons:
    # Is this face selected?
    if polygon.select:
        # Print UV vertices of this face
        for loop_index in polygon.loop_indices:
            print(uv_layer[loop_index].uv)
print()

# Return to original mode
if obj_mode != 'OBJECT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=obj_mode)
```